# Could creating an event be a valid way to make a XF OnAppearing into an async method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently saw this suggestion on how to make an app OnStart into an async OnStart:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        this.started += onStarted;      //Subscribe to event
        started(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
    }

    protected async void onStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            await // do things
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ignore = ex;
        }
        this.started -= onStarted;
    }
```

Can anyone see any possible issues with this and if not then could something similar be applied to the OnAppearing and if so would there be any changes needed.

Comment: you can make `OnStart` and `OnAppearing` `async` by just adding the `async` keyword

Comment: Are both OnStart and OnAppearing both just events in XF ?

Comment: They are lifecycle events to be specific!

Comment: It depends on what are you going to accomplish with this event.

Comment: @Alan2 `OnStart` and `OnAppearing` are both `void` methods that are called as part of the raised lifecycle events. They are not to be mistaken for event handlers. The approach shown in your example can also be applied to `OnAppearing`.

Answer (score 5):

`OnAppearing` is simply a `void` method on Page class

*Xamarin.Forms.Page*

```
//...

protected virtual void OnAppearing()
{
}

//...
```

[Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L282)

that is called as part of the Page's life cycle.

```
//...

[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public void SendAppearing()
{
    if (_hasAppeared)
        return;

    _hasAppeared = true;

    if (IsBusy)
    {
        if (IsPlatformEnabled)
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, BusySetSignalName, true);
        else
            _pendingActions.Add(() => MessagingCenter.Send(this, BusySetSignalName, true));
    }

    OnAppearing(); //<---
    Appearing?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //NOTE HOW ACTUAL EVENT IS RAISED AFTER

    var pageContainer = this as IPageContainer<Page>;
    pageContainer?.CurrentPage?.SendAppearing();

    FindApplication(this)?.OnPageAppearing(this);
}

//...
```

[Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L413)

**They are not to be mistaken for event handlers**, that are the one exception allowed to use `async void`.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

The approach shown in your `OnStart` example can also be applied to `OnAppearing`

For example

```
public partial class SomePage : ContentPage {
    public SomelPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        appearing += onAppearing;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        appearing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        appearing -= onAppearing;
    }

    event EventHandler appearing = delegate { };

    private async void onAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            var places = await SomeService.getPlacesOfInterest(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            placesListView.ItemsSource = places;
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            //handler error (Log?)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could subscribe to the **actual** `Appearing` event directly

```
//...

public event EventHandler Appearing;

//...
```

[Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L177)

and forgo overriding the `OnAppearing()` method

```
public partial class SomePage : ContentPage {
    public SomelPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Appearing += onAppearing;
    }

    private async void onAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            var places = await SomeService.getPlacesOfInterest(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            placesListView.ItemsSource = places;
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            //handler error (Log?)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you don't call base.OnAppearing in the examples above. Is that something that should also be done there and also in the OnStart() that I used in the question as an example? The reason I ask is that I see you  are saying it's a virtual method but I think I recall seeing many examples where base.OnAppearing is called.

Comment: @Alan2 In this case I don't because based on the source code nothing else overrides that base member which is empty. If there was functionality in the base then sure, call it. If deriving from a 3rd party type then to be safe, call base if you don't know if the base class has overridden functionality.