# If OnAppearing in Xamarin forms is a lifecycle event then why do people add in a base.OnAppearing?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I see this often:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
```

Why do people add base.OnAppearing()

Also:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
```

Is it needed to override OnStart and is that also a similar lifecycle event?

Comment: It depends on you ,that's just a default code generated style . If need to invoke the superclass method in subclass , you can use `base.xxx()` to do that . You can understand it shows the features of polymorphism in C sharp language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnAppearing` is a virtual method defined in the [`Xamarin.Forms.Page`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L282) class

```cs
namespace Xamarin.Forms
{
    [RenderWith(typeof(_PageRenderer))]
    public class Page : VisualElement, ILayout, IPageController, IElementConfiguration<Page>, IPaddingElement
    {
        // ...
        protected virtual void OnAppearing()
        {
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

and [gets also called](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Page.cs#L413) from the base class

```cs
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public void SendAppearing()
{
    if (_hasAppeared)
        return;

    _hasAppeared = true;

    if (IsBusy)
    {
        if (IsPlatformEnabled)
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, BusySetSignalName, true);
        else
            _pendingActions.Add(() => MessagingCenter.Send(this, BusySetSignalName, true));
    }

    OnAppearing(); // <--- here
    Appearing?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    var pageContainer = this as IPageContainer<Page>;
    pageContainer?.CurrentPage?.SendAppearing();

    FindApplication(this)?.OnPageAppearing(this);
}
```

It is very common to call the base method within an overridden method.

Comment: Okay thanks,  someone else had told me that it was a lifecycle event so I didn't realize it was still a method.  How about OnStart? Is that the same.  I had another question that I opened as I was asking about a clean way to make an async OnAppearing.  I'd be interesting to hear your comments on this or perhaps the question is something you could consider answering:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472328/could-creating-an-event-be-a-valid-way-to-make-a-xf-onappearing-into-an-async-me

Comment: Looking at the sources [method](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/655fa004f60e3cfc3820f9a83e7016c763d3ac42/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Application.cs#L229) and [caller](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/655fa004f60e3cfc3820f9a83e7016c763d3ac42/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Application.cs#L292)  ... yes

Comment: Okay thanks.  I will be sure to call the base class as I was not previously calling it for OnStart override

Comment: Also interested to hear your opinion on the way I saw to make an async OnStart listed in the question I mention in above comments.

Comment: Just flag the overridden OnStart method with the async keyword. The extra event will only add some more overhead and nothing more.

Comment: And yes, the Xamarin Fraework did not offer you a strict clean way to have an overridden async OnStart method. The question is: What would be the benefit if we would have such an async OnStart methed we could override? Is there any one except from clean implementation?